# Use variable from file to push data through JSON

Tags: bash, json

I'm currently stuck where I try to push data through API that requires JSON structure. I need to read value from file, where I wrote:

```
file="/value"
name=$(cat "$file")
```

So $name is variable for the content inside value file, and that works just fine, the problem comes when I need to push data:

```
cos -u https://myapi.com push data '{
  "sec": 0,
  "usage": 0,
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "transfer",
      "data": {
        "from": "test",
        "to": "test2",
        "value": $name,
        "message": ""
  },
```

How can I define to read name variable on "value" object?

Comment: single quotes `'` disable interpolation of variables, so you will need to use `"... $name ..."` instead, and then escape all the internal `"` with `\"`

Comment: @thrig ... and the data in the file needs to be encoded into a single JSON string, presumably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data in your file should be taken as a raw string, it would need to be JSON-encoded.  It is easiest to do that with a program that understands JSON, like `jq`:

```bash
json='
{
   "actions": [
      {
         "data": { "from": "test", "message": "", "to": "test2" },
         "name": "transfer"
      }
   ],
   "sec": 0,
   "usage": 0
}
'

json=$( jq --arg value "$(cat "$file")" '.actions[0].data.value = $value' <<<"$json" )

cos -u 'https://myapi.com' push data "$json"
```

Note that `$value` in the `jq` expression is not a shell variable but an internal `jq` variable whose value is given on the command line with `--arg` and that it's automatically JSON-encoded.

A slightly more convenient way to handle the data in `$file` without having to expand it on the command line (which would matter if the amount of data is large) is to convert the data to a JSON string separately and pass it to the `jq` that inserts it in the correct place via a process substitution:

```bash
jq '.actions[0].data.value = input' - <( jq -Rs . data ) <<<"$json"
```

---

You could also use `jo` to create the `data` object with the `value` key's value read from the `$file` file and then just insert that with a shell variable:

```bash
datajson=$( jo from=test message="" to="test2" value=@"$file" )

json='
{
   "actions": [
      {
         "data": '"$datajson"',
         "name": "transfer"
      }
   ],
   "sec": 0,
   "usage": 0
}
'

cos -u 'https://myapi.com' push data "$json"
```

Note how we temporarily break out of the single-quoted string that makes up the JSON document to insert the quoted expansion of `$datajson`.